# DataContractJsonSerializer cannot deserialize Newtonsoft JsonSerializer

Tags: c#, json, json.net, datacontractjsonserializer

What do first 3 bytes written by JsonSerializer on the begging of stream mean and why does DataContractJsonSerializer have a problem with them?

Sample:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    //serialize using JsonSerializer
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8, 4096, true))
    using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
    {
        JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create();
        jsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, foo, typeof(Foo));
    }

    // reset position
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    // deserialize using DataContractJsonSerializer
    using (var jsonReader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max, null))
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer dataContractJsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Foo));
        foo = (Foo)dataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(jsonReader);
    }
}
```

Deserialization ends up with exception: `Additional information: There was an error deserializing the object of type Sandbox.Program+Foo. Encountered unexpected character 'ï'.`

Comment: Don't even try. DataContractJsonSerializer is *ancient*, obsolete and created before there was any form of standardization for Json. For example, when DataContractJsonSerializer was created there was no JSon date format, so it used a Unix timestamp (ie number of ms since 1970-01-01). The ISO 8601 was adopted years later

Comment: PS the first 3 bytes are the Unicode BOM. These have nothing to do with JSon. These are artifacts of the stream writers.

Comment: About `DataContractJsonSerializer` - I'm not, server side does and I've forgot about BOM, little bit embarrassing.

Comment: You *could* run into trouble though, if the server tried to send dates. BTW even whitespace handling wasn't standardized until a few years ago, with naive implementations choking eg with newlines inside strings

Comment: Does doing `var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false), 4096, true)` as @PanagiotisKanavos suggested solve the problem?